# What is the htaccess code that combines a Wordpress permalink and a password protected directory?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, passwords

right now /members is a password protected directory via the hosting control panel using htaccess

When I create a Wordpress page with /members as the Permalink, then login using the standard grey popup login screen, it does not display the /members content I just created in Wordpress.

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is that?

Because you're password protecting the physical *directory* `members`, but not the Wordpress permalink. Your browser's request never gets through to the physical directory.

I don't think it's possible to protect specific WordPress URLs this way - you may need to find a way to do this within Wordpress (like a Plugin).